# How to set a navigation bar with title in popover controller

Tags: ipad

How do you set a navigation bar with a title in a popover controller? I want a detailed explanation, please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SomeViewController *popContentViewController = [[SomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:popContentViewController];
UIPopoverController popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller]; 
popOverController.delegate = self;
[popContentViewController release];
[controller release];
```

And in SomeViewController Class in viewDidLoad method write

```
self.title = @"Text For Title on Navigation Bar";
```

Comment: haii sir,did u look into my code?

Comment: "please mister kindly do my homework"